# How to combine two or more columns of data table to one column?

Tags: r, datatable, multiple-columns

I'm having a data table, which can look like this:

```
year <- c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018")
month <- c("01","01","01","01")
day <- c("01", "02","03","04")
hour <- c("00","01","02","03")
id <- c(8750, 3048, 3593, 8475)
type <- c("ist","plan","ist","plan")

dt.test <- data.table(year, month, day, hour, id, type)
```

Now I want to combine the columns `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour` to a single column called `date` of the form `"2018-01-01 00"`, `"2018-01-02 01"` and so on.  In the end I need a data table with the columns `date` (combined one), `id` and `type`. I know how to do this with `paste()`, but is there another fast and efficient way to do so?

Comment: `paste` should really be fast. How are you using it and how big is your data?

Comment: I would use it likes this: ``dt.result$date1 <- paste(dt.test$year, dt.test$month, dt.test$day, sep = "-")``
``dt.result$date <- paste(dt.result$date1, dt.test$hour)``... My data table is around 1GB (I have more rows and columns than the example of my question). So it takes some time.

Comment: Does `tidyr::unite` help ? `dt.test <- tidyr::unite(dt.test, date, year:hour, sep = '-')`

Comment: Thank you! This is faster than my ``paste``-version.

Comment: You have a `data.table`, so why not create your columns by reference?

Comment: @Henrik how to do so?

Comment: Please study the vignettes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tidyr::unite` -

```
dt.test <- tidyr::unite(dt.test, date, year:hour, sep = '-')
dt.test

#            date   id type
#1: 2018-01-01-00 8750  ist
#2: 2018-01-02-01 3048 plan
#3: 2018-01-03-02 3593  ist
#4: 2018-01-04-03 8475 plan
```

Comment: This doesn't give the format as specified though - there's a space between the day and the hour instead of a dash. That'll contribute quite a bit because you only need one paste operation as opposed to two.

Comment: If you have [a look under the hood](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/R/unite.R) `unite` boils down to `paste` and `paste0`.